# change the absolute position from left to right on a span tag depending on class

Tags: php, html, css, css-position

This is my first question here but I'm sure there are many more to come.
I have a small position problem that I would like to know if it's even possible to achieve.

I have an unordered list (`<ul>`) with floated `<li>`s, for the main options i float these left, and for the contact and support options I float them right, so far so good. Now i have a `<span>` inside each `<li>` which i display under the horizontal list, the list is for a menu. These `<span>`s works as description to menu choice and for the normal options I use `position:absolute; top:30px; left:0;` this works as suspected. Now I would like to change the position attributes for those menu items that i float right so that the span gets `position:absolute; top:30px; right:0;` and this doesn't work at all. It seems like it's impossible to change this with a more specific css rule then the other, yet the float works great.

the html:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li>Menu1<span>Info1</span></li>
    <li>Menu2<span>Info2</span></li>
    <li class="support">Support1<span>Info3</span></li>
</ul>
```

The css:

```
#menu{position:relative;}
#menu ul{list-style:none;}
#menu ul li{float:left;}
#menu ul li.support{float:right;}
#menu ul li span{display:none;}
#menu ul li:hover span{display:block; position:absolute; top:30px; left:0;}
#menu ul li.support:hover span{display:block; position:absolute; top:30px; right:0}
```

The last line in the css make no difference!
If anyone has an answer or a work around I greatly appreciate the help.

Question answered and problem solved. Check James Arons or mercator's posts.

Comment: Thanks very much, though I am not the Qer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even thought you set `right:0`, your `left:0` is still being inherited. You need to set `left:auto` to override that style for the `support` class.

Answer (score 6):

Judging from that CSS, you don't seem to understand CSS correctly, or you aren't using it correctly at least. You might want to read the SitePoint article about [the cascade, specificity and inheritance](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritancecascade) for a good introduction.

The reason that doesn't work is because the last *two* lines of that CSS apply to the list items with the `support` class. The second-to-last line applies to *all* list items, and the last line then adds to that for the `support` list items. So, since there's no `left` property in that last line, the `left` property cascades down from the previous line, making it `left: 0` *too*.

When you're using a class to mark a special case, you shouldn't be repeating all the CSS of the general case, but only provide the CSS necessary to change it:

```
#menu ul li:hover span {display:block; position:absolute; top:30px; left:0;}
#menu ul li.support:hover span {left:auto; right:0;}
```

That CSS will mean the `support`-class list items get all the CSS the other list items get, but with the `left` property reset to default, and the `right` property set instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm weird. I can't tell you why your code does not work, should work since the support:hover span is a more specific selector.

Found a fix though:
Position absolute elements got left: 0; by default.
If you remove left: 0; from the span selector it will work.

Your code would look like this:

```
#menu{position:relative;}
#menu ul{list-style:none;}
#menu ul li{float:left;}
#menu ul li.support{float:right;}
#menu ul li span{display:none;}
#menu ul li:hover span{display:block; position:absolute; top:30px;}
#menu ul li.support:hover span{display:block; position:absolute; top:30px; right:0}
```